# The present continuous vs. the 'going to' construction for future events

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous, future-time, periphrastic-modals

Is there any slight difference between the two sentences below?

> 1. **I’m taking** the car to the mechanic’s shop tomorrow.
> 2. **I’m going to take** the car to the mechanic’s shop tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference in the meaning of the two sentences.

If you said "I **was** going to ..." then that would imply that you had changed your mind or that something had happened  to frustrate your previous intention.